# document.createElement on table,tr,td tags fails IE8

Tags: javascript, createelement

As the title says, I'm having an issue with IE8 (works in FF and IE9). The following code doesn't produce any errors, and if I substitute div,ul,and li; it works. I did some searching and didn't find anything on (table,tr,td) tags not being supported using `document.createElement` with IE8. Where am I going wrong?

Here is the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>My Page Title</title>
  <script>
    function init() {
      var ele = document.getElementById('content');
      var table = document.createElement('table');
      var tr = document.createElement('tr');
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      var txt = document.createTextNode('IE8');

      td.appendChild(txt);
      tr.appendChild(td);
      table.appendChild(tr);
      ele.appendChild(table);
    }
   </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init();">
    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using IE10 and it seems to work in IE8, IE9, and IE10 mode. It does _not_ work in IE7 mode though.

Comment: @MichaelTodd, The IE8 Document Mode was set to Quirks. Switching to IE8 Standards did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use only `createElement()` function to create `table,` `tr`, `td` to create whole table element.

Instead you have to use `insertRow()`, `insertCell()` function of table Object

For Reference check this:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript/

**Edit:**

Even I was thinking in the same way for IE issues , 
Buy I found  that actually for `createElement()` to work in IE7 you have to create `tbody` object and append that to the `table` object and `tr` to that `tbody` object

```
tb = document.createElement("tbody")  
var tbody  = document.createElement('tbody'); 
table.appendChild(tbody);
var table_row  = document.createElement('tr'); 
tbody.appendChild(table_row)//
```

Answer (score 1):

just add `<!DOCTYPE html>` in markup.
In IE7 and above default rendering without DOCTYPE is Quirks mode (IE5).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  var ele = document.getElementById('content');
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  ele.appendChild(table);
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  table.appendChild(tr);
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  tr.appendChild(td);
  var txt = document.createTextNode('IE8');
  td.appendChild(txt);
```