# HTML form output as a table

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have developed the HTML form, which pretty much looks as below:

[image]

Afterwards, I've prepared an external html file, where this form output is located. I've followed the tutorial below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNcJuPIZ2WE&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified

Next, because I get only pure data after colon, I decided to collect them in the table.

In this case I modified the javascript code:

```
    <table id="opresults"></table>

    <script>
        const resultsList = document.getElementById('opresults')
        const matches = document.querySelectorAll("fieldset");
        new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).forEach((value, name) => {
            resultsList.append(`<th>${name}</th><td>${value}</td>`)
            resultsList.append(document.createElement('br'))
        })
    </script>
```

by changing the `resultsList.append`, where instead of
resultsList.append(`${name}: ${value}`)

I've put
resultsList.append(`<th>${name}</th><td>${value}</td>`)

with hope, that I will get the table instead.

Unfortunately, the  and  is only appended to the text and nothing changes really.
Moreover it applies to other HTML attributes like   and so on.

How can I make the table from the data presented below?

[image]

I saw in this example:

[build a list with Javascript append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203315/build-a-list-with-javascript-append)

that it's fairly possible

**UPDATE:**

After another approach, my code looks like this:

```
<table id="opresults">Survey Form
    <tr>
       <th> Form question</th>
       <th>Answer</th>
    </tr>
    <tr >

    </tr>
</table>

 <script>
        const resultsList = document.getElementById('opresults')
        const matches = document.querySelectorAll("fieldset"); 
        <th>code</th></tr>'));
        new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).forEach((value, name) => 
            {
            resultsList.append(document.createElement('td'))
           
            resultsList.append(`${name}: ${value}`)
     
            resultsList.append(document.createElement('br'))
        })
    </script>
```

[image]

I want to have it in 2 columns. What is missing here?

Comment: Please read an introductory guide to HTML and learn about the `table` element the `tr` element and how a `br` element isn't allowed inside either.

Comment: And read what [`.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) does and how the type of its argument influences that behavior.

Comment: Please post relevant code instead of screenshots.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ratcbe9h/  here is the code

Answer (score 0):

The proper HTML table structure is required at the very beginning.

```
      <table id="opresults" class="outputtable"><p class="outputtablehead">Survey Form - output</p>
    <tr class="colname">
       <th>Form question</th>
        <th colspan="2">Answer</th>
    </tr>

</table>
```

and next in our javascript code we should split the `append` attribute between the `name` and `value` separately, placing the table attributes between them

```
     <script>
        const resultsList = document.getElementById('opresults')
        const matches = document.querySelectorAll("fieldset");

        new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).forEach((value, name) => {
            resultsList.append(document.createElement('tbody'))
            resultsList.append(`${name}`)
            resultsList.append(document.createElement('td'))
            resultsList.append(`${value}`)
            resultsList.append(document.createElement('br'))   
        })
    </script>
```

[image]

A quite good solution was here:

[document.createElement on table,tr,td tags fails IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889840/document-createelement-on-table-tr-td-tags-fails-ie8)